# Visual Studio Code not recognizing the built-in typescript definition files

Tags: visual-studio-code, typescript1.5

I've been trying to create a hello-world sample with TypeScript (1.5 beta) and AngularJS (1.4) using Visual Studio Code (0.3.0) editor. As shown in the snapshot below, when the code references AngularJS' TypeScript definition file, VS Code throws a lot of errors.
[image]

[image]

Not sure what wrong I am doing here.

** Edit **
The typings are installed by first running `npm install -g typescript` and then `tsd install [library-name] --save`

Considering the comments from GJSmith3rd, building the project outputs the --help command of tsc. See below:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I take it that you solved the issue yourself? Cool! Please don't edit your question, instead write an answer and accept it. This makes it explicit that the problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: @Stefan: Sorry for the confusion. But that's just one of the steps I performed trying to solve the problem, but still no luck. I just wanted to state that I took the latest typescript and then installed the typings via tsd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Typescript in VSCode is working fine with your example.**

1. Create a new folder in VSCode
2. Create a simple tsconfig.json file with compiler options

   ```
   {
       "compilerOptions": {
           "target": "ES3",
           "module": "amd",
           "sourceMap": false
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create example code to in app.ts

   ```
   export interface IPerson {
       firstName: string;
       lastName: string;
   }

   export class Person implements IPerson {
       constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string) {
           var module = angular.module("myApp", []);
       }
   }
   ```
4. **IMPORTANT:** Use [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd) `tsd` command
   `$tsd install angular jquery --save` from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd). Angular depends on jQuery.
5. Add a `tsd.d.ts` file reference to `app.ts`

   ```
   /// <reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts" />
   ```
6. Configure a Task Runner in `.settings/tasks.json` in directory of the app by using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and select "Configure Task Runner". Remove the contents of `"args:[Hello World],` or create a new similar task with `"args:[],`
7. Compile with Task Runner with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>

[image]

Here's the uncommented task runner I used `"args": [],`

```
// A task runner that calls the Typescipt compiler (tsc) and 
// Compiles a app.ts program
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
    "command": "tsc",

    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur. 
    "showOutput": "silent",

    // args is the app.ts program to compile.
    "args": [],

    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

If there are still problems with compiling in VSCode try the command line from the project directory for clues.

```
tsc --module amd  --out app.js app.ts
```

and check your version as mentioned earlier:

`02:00:23 ツ gjsmith3rd@DV7:~/Workspaces/Examples/TypeScript/MSDN/MyProject5 >tsc --version
message TS6029: Version 1.5.3`

Consider updating tsc to the latest version which at the time of this edit is v1.5.3 with `sudo npm install tsc -g`.

Comment: Thanks @GJSmith3rd. I performed everything till step 6. When I compile the task runner, it outputs nothing. I pressed CTRL+SHIFT+U to see the tasks output, and it output --help of tsd. Does it has anything to do with typescript or tsd version?

Comment: just curious to know, are you using atom-typescript?

Comment: Did you start from a fresh folder? Also did you 'tsd install angular jquery --save' to install tsd.d.ts for both jQuery and Angular and ref the combined file? I doubt it's a typescript or tsd version problem. I think you need to make sure you have tsd references for both Angular and jQuery and reference them with the single tsd.d.ts file.

Comment: Edited my question with updated snapshots.Please have a look. I performed the steps exactly as you mentioned, but still no luck

Comment: Well my tsc --version yields Version 1.5.0-beta and I just updated to 1.5.3 with `sudo npm install tsc -g`.  I'm running GNU/Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: The tsc was out of date, as a result, it was showing all those wierd errors. Thanks for your time, marking your answer.

Comment: addition of a tsconfig.json file solved my issue, thanks man.